# JS Hamburger Menu Not Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to close my Hamburger menu using JS but it's not working, can anyone let me know what's wrong with this?

```
window.onload = function() {
    var buttons = $('#buttons01');
    buttons.each( function () {
        var t = $(this);
        t.find('li').addClass('x');
        t.prepend('<li class="toggle"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>');
        
        var toggle = t.find('.toggle');
        toggle.on("click", function() {
            if (t.hasClass('active')) {
                t.removeClass('active');
            } else {
                t.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
}

// close hamburger menu after click a
$('toggle').on("click", function(){
    $('#toggle').click();
});
```

Comment: `$( 'toggle' ).on("click", ...` what's `$('toggle')` here?

Comment: `$('toggle')` should be `$('.toggle')`?

Comment: Also, `#toggle` should be `.toggle` since there is no element with an ID of 'toggle'.